# How to calculate area of visibility analysis

Tags: qgis, visibility

I created visibility analysis in QGIS and I don't know how to measure visible area. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: If you visibility analysis is a raster, you can convert it to a vector and use the field calculator to get the area. There are several solutions out there if you search for qgis raster area.

Comment: Thank you, i will check this